# How to map "new" property in subclass with Fluent NHibernate?

Tags: c#, subclass, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

A have the following classes:

```
public class Parent  
{    
  ...    
  public virtual property IList<ParentParam> Parameters { get; set; } 
}

public class ParentParam { ... }

public class Child: Parent {
  public new virtual property IList<ChildParam> Parameters { get; set; }
}

public class ChildParam : ParentParam { ... }
```

How do I map the child class, so the Parameters returned are the correct type? I tried simply mapping the property, and it did not work.

```
public class ParentMap: ClassMap<Parent>
{
    public ParentMap()
    {
        ...
        HasMany(x => x.Parameters).Cascade.All();
    }
}

public class ChildMap: SubclassMap<Child>
{
    public ChildMap()
    {
        ...
        HasMany(x => x.Parameters).Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

Comment: ever figure this out?

Comment: No, the problem persist